# Show the image specified in src

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to find a way to state "if" there is an image in the description of a Wordpress post show the image specified in src instead of from the data-img attribute. Right now I'm using a JS plugin called Superbox ( http://bvh.delineamultimedia.com/wp-content/themes/bvh/js/portfolio/superbox.js ) and its not picking up the images showin in my description area of Wordpress because the data-img attribute is null But I'd like it to show the image specified from the src. Instead its showing a Cannot read property 'img' of null in the console currently.

Is there a way in this statement to say if img's data-img attribute is null in .description show it anyways?

```
if (imgData.description) {
    superboxcontent.append('<div class="description">' + imgData.description + '</div>');
}
```

Thanks in advance! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: jQuery: `$('img').attr('src');` You need to put it into superbox.

Comment: I'll try this. Is there a certain line that it would go best on?

Comment: Selecting `$('img')` will select every image on th page. You need to look at the class.

Comment: Yea I think it need to state if there is a img in the description display it from the src.

Comment: Not what I meant. Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?